# Removing LaunchScreen.xib from a project

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, xib, launch-screen

Is it safe to remove LaunchScreen.xib from Xcode 6 project when is not used i.e. Images.xcassets is used instead ?

What is the proper way to remove it ? There is a property in info.plist called *Launch screen interface file base name* with value `LaunchScreen` so I guess that should be removed also?

Are there any more associated files with LaunchScreen.xib in Xcode 6 project which should be removed if LaunchScreen.xib is deleted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. Just select the file in the XCode, press delete and choose "Move to Trash". The property in the .plist wil be automatically modified.

Comment: You can recreate the file anytime later.

Comment: Actually "Move To Trash" doesn't automatically alter the .plist. To achieve that I had to remove the value "LaunchScreen" from General Target Settings->App icons and launch images->Launch image file. After that, info.plist was automatically updated. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Do not forget, your application has to have appropriate launch image or launch screen to submit it into App Store.

Comment: @Whirlwind How to remove the value "LaunchScreen" from General Target Settings->App icons and launch images->Launch image file. Is it in xCode or by hand in files?

Answer (score 0):

**This answer resolve my issue:**

You can do it by changing the "Launch Screen file" under your target settings on the General tab, Check this link:

http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/